# Why is averageRating always 0?

Tags: here-api

I am using the 'Explore Popular Places by Category' API and it always returns averageRating as 0 for all items in the result.

I made this call with various categories such as restaurants and sights-museums, but it always returns 0 for averageRating. Does HERE not provide this detail, and if so, why is it returned in the response?

Some details:

I am making a call to this url:

```
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=52.5159%2C13.3777&cat=sights-museums&apiKey={api_key}
```

and it returns something like this:

```
{
  "results": {
    "next": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/explore;context=Y2F0PXNpZ2h0cy1tdXNldW1zJmZsb3ctaWQ9Mjk0ZjU1NTgtMmY0Mi01Y2FiLWJlYWUtOGEyM2ViY2EzMzgzXzE1ODMyNjMyNjEwMzZfMF84NTcyJm9mZnNldD0yMCZzaXplPTIw?at=52.5159%2C13.3777&app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
    "items": [
      {
        "position": [
          52.51629,
          13.37817
        ],
        "distance": 54,
        "title": "Brandenburg Gate",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "landmark-attraction",
          "title": "Landmark/Attraction",
          "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/landmark-attraction?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.data.here.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/38.icon",
        "vicinity": "Pariser Platz<br/>Mitte, 10117 Berlin",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/276u33db-8ee2e0de906e459cbade0593986debe9;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0yOTRmNTU1OC0yZjQyLTVjYWItYmVhZS04YTIzZWJjYTMzODNfMTU4MzI2MzI2MTAzNl8wXzg1NzImcmFuaz0w?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
        "id": "276u33db-8ee2e0de906e459cbade0593986debe9",
        "alternativeNames": [
          {
            "name": "Brandenburger Tor",
            "language": "de"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": [
          52.51373,
          13.37976
        ],
        "distance": 279,
        "title": "Holocaust Memorial",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "museum",
          "title": "Museum",
          "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/museum?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.data.here.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/10.icon",
        "vicinity": "Cora-Berliner-Straße 1<br/>Mitte, 10117 Berlin",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/276u33de-df7d57fd38494a93b2018fe549a0fd75;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0yOTRmNTU1OC0yZjQyLTVjYWItYmVhZS04YTIzZWJjYTMzODNfMTU4MzI2MzI2MTAzNl8wXzg1NzImcmFuaz0x?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
        "id": "276u33de-df7d57fd38494a93b2018fe549a0fd75",
        "openingHours": {
          "text": "Tue-Sun: 10:00 - 20:00",
          "label": "Opening hours",
          "isOpen": false,
          "structured": [
            {
              "start": "T100000",
              "duration": "PT10H00M",
              "recurrence": "FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU"
            }
          ]
        },
        "alternativeNames": [
          {
            "name": "Memorial to the Murdered European Jews",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "name": "Memorial to the Murdered Jews of Europe",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "name": "Denkmal für die ermordeten Juden Europas",
            "language": "de"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": [
          52.51666,
          13.40784
        ],
        "distance": 2041,
        "title": "Nicholas Quarter",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "museum",
          "title": "Museum",
          "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/museum?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.data.here.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/10.icon",
        "vicinity": "Nikolaikirchplatz<br/>Mitte, 10178 Berlin",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/276u33dc-049683d3c6be4bdba823808678a1b164;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0yOTRmNTU1OC0yZjQyLTVjYWItYmVhZS04YTIzZWJjYTMzODNfMTU4MzI2MzI2MTAzNl8wXzg1NzImcmFuaz0xOQ?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q",
        "id": "276u33dc-049683d3c6be4bdba823808678a1b164",
        "alternativeNames": [
          {
            "name": "Nikolaiviertel",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "name": "Nikolaiviertel",
            "language": "de"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "search": {
    "context": {
      "location": {
        "position": [
          52.5159,
          13.3777
        ],
        "address": {
          "text": "Ebertstraße 22<br/>Mitte, 10117 Berlin<br/>Germany",
          "house": "22",
          "street": "Ebertstraße",
          "postalCode": "10117",
          "district": "Mitte",
          "city": "Berlin",
          "county": "Berlin",
          "stateCode": "Berlin",
          "country": "Germany",
          "countryCode": "DEU"
        }
      },
      "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
      "href": "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPUViZXJ0c3RyYSVDMyU5RmUrMjI7bGF0PTUyLjUxNTk7bG9uPTEzLjM3Nzc7c3RyZWV0PUViZXJ0c3RyYSVDMyU5RmU7aG91c2U9MjI7Y2l0eT1CZXJsaW47cG9zdGFsQ29kZT0xMDExNztjb3VudHJ5PURFVTtkaXN0cmljdD1NaXR0ZTtzdGF0ZUNvZGU9QmVybGluO2NvdW50eT1CZXJsaW47Y2F0ZWdvcnlJZD1idWlsZGluZztzb3VyY2VTeXN0ZW09aW50ZXJuYWw;context=c2VhcmNoQ29udGV4dD0x?app_id=LKO34glU2MBEVbcOD5mQ&app_code=A2ta_nQ8HRYwenju5HFG5Q"
    }
  }
}
```

Does HERE not provide the averageRatings of restaurants or sights-museums?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! According to the HERE documentation, if no ratings have been filed yet the averageRating will be 0. I'm not sure where HERE gets their ratings from, but it is possible that there aren't many locations with ratings.

Comment: Ok, so i went o colosseum and it's rate is 0... i gues that is just not working at all

Answer (score 0):

From the docs it appears if the place hasn't received a rating it'll be 0

> Note: If the place has no ratings (yet), both the average and the count values are zero. But if the place cannot be rated (i.e. a street), the whole rating object is not present.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/object-rating.html

Comment: 1. The returned response does not follow the schema mentioned in the doc (it does not contain the ratings count). 2. I get averageRating as 0 every single time. I have tried with multiple locations and categories (even the restaurants in Manhattan have 0 ratings)

Comment: I would be inclined to say that it will still default to 0. Reach out to them if unsure